# CSS pseudo-classes and required

Tags: html, css

There are two CSS pseudo-classes, `:invalid` and `:valid`, there are work only if input have required (http://jsfiddle.net/d26jf/ the input is everytime red, even when it is invalid). Using required you can't send a input when it is empty (http://jsfiddle.net/d26jf/2/ in mozilla appear a popup that advise you to compile the input). How to use `:invalid` and `:valid` without use required (which blocks the sending of empty input)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `novalidate` (on the `<form>`) or `formnovalidate` (on the `<input>` itself) to skip validation on form submission.  `:valid` and `:invalid` still seem to work with the validation rules in spite of this attribute's existence.

http://jsfiddle.net/d26jf/4/

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo class `:invalid` is for required and `:valid` which is for not required [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d26jf/3/).

So, you need to set which field is required and not required. You can't do the both `:valid and :invalid` for required field. For more info see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid)

Comment: Yes but, i want to send the input even if it is empty, but i want to use :invalid and :valid. If I use required for use both and input is empty, i can't send it and i want to send it even if it is empty. How to do?